# A monster integral

Tags: integration

I have this homework question in a first course of calculus.

[image]

The instruction ask to solve the integrals by substitute *a*=6 and *b*=6

My guess is to try to solve it by split the integral in 5 more simple ones.

[image]

**I ask my teacher for some leads, he insist that there is no problem with the integral, also didn't tell me more.  I need to know if it is possible to solve the integral without imaginary numbers and other issues that not concern to the first calculus semester?  What do you think?**

Comment: There is no need to do any integral. The $\sec^6(x)\tan^6(x)$ part of the integrand has two non-integrable singularities at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ in $[1,6]$ and nothing in the rest of the integrand that kills it. Furthermore, since the exponential of the $\int \sin^6(x)\cos^6(x)$ is positive and finite. If you insist to give a number to the integral, the number should be $\infty$.

Comment: In B) the integrand is a complex-valued function. Taking  $-1=i^2$ out the root, 
we obtain the real-valued integral wich can be calculated step by step with Maple 17 by
$$with(Student[Calculus1]):
IntTutor(12*x/sqrt(x^2+6*x-6), x = 1 .. 6);$$ See [the output](http://rapidshare.com/files/1863558545/screen13.09.13.docx).

Comment: @achillehui You are right! I didn't realize that it was a *definite* integral.

Comment: isn't there a missing $dx$?

Comment: I think so, and also seems to me that there is a missing x in the cosine of the exponential integral (the second integral), Don't you think?

Comment: @achillehui Put your comment as an answer, otherwise me or another user will undeservedly receive the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $u=\tan(x)$ then $du=\sec^2(x)\,dx$ and $\sec^{2m}(x)=(1+\tan^2(x))^m=(1+u^2)^m$.